# Getting current tabs and selected tab URL on Chrome API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-app-developer-tool

I am trying to get the `URL` of all opened Tabs and Selected Tab using these two snippets:

```
// For Getting URL of All Opened Tabs
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tabs) {
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    console.log(tab.url);
     }
});

// For Getting URL of Selected Tab
chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab) {
     console.log(tab.url);
});
```

but neither of them working. For getting all tabs I am getting this error:

> Error in response to tabs.getCurrent: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

and for getting the selected tab:

> undefined

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Always check the parameters in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). Even I do that. `getCurrent` returns a single tab where the invoking code runs. `getSelected` is deprecated, don't use it. Also your question has conflicting tags: apps aren't extensions.

Comment: Also, the devtools built-in debugger is an excellent tool where you can set breakpoints and inspect parameters and anything instead of guessing what's wrong.

Comment: Your first error is because you are using the variable name `tab`, which you have never defined. Thus, it is undefined. That portion of your code needs to be completely reworked for other reasons.  The second one is unclear. Please supply a *manifest.json* so we can see if you have declared the `tabs` permission. Not doing so would cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected` [has been deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected). so we should use `tabs.query({active: true}...` instead.

`chrome.tabs.getCurrent` passes a [single tab to the callback function](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent). It doesn't *"Getting URL of All Opened Tabs"*, it:

> Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. May be undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example: a background page or popup view).

So:

```
// Write the URL of the current tab to the console
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => console.log(tab.url));
```

This requires the `"activeTab"` or `"tabs"` permission in the manifest. If there is an error it won't throw an exception, instead it will populate [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError).

I find it easier to deal with all the callbacks using an asynchronous or promise wrapper library like [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync). This let's us use `async`/`await` syntax and a regular `try-catch`:

```
try {
    const currentTab = await chrome.tabs.getCurrent();
    console.log(currentTab.url);
}
catch(err) {
    // Handle errors
}
```

In your `popup.html` you can't access `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` - you have to use `chrome.tabs.query` instead:

```
async function writeAllTabUrlToConsole() {
    try {
        // Get all the tabs
        const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});

        // Write all their URLs to the popup's console
        for(let t of tabs)
            console.log(t.url, t.active);
    }
    catch(err) {
        // Handle errors
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith but neither of you hints are not working on my side! the `chrome.tabs.getCurrent(tab => console.log(tab.url));` is genereting  this error `Error in response to tabs.getCurrent: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` and the last code I am getting  `Invocation of form tabs.query() doesn't match definition tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback)`

Comment: @Behseini I think `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` returns `undefined` because your code is running in a pop-up. The last code had a bug in it (my fault) - `chrome.tabs.query` always needs a `queryInfo` object, even if getting all tabs. Try changing it to `chrome.tabs.query({})`